# Functionally prepending an array element

Tags: javascript, mongodb, functional-programming

Is there a functional way to prepend an element to an array. Something like:

```
[1,2].prepend(3); // should return [3, 1, 2]
```

Kindly notice that a reference to the **result** array is returned. The reason is to be able to do more things with the same array.

PS: I am asking about the MongoDB command-line interface.

PPS: I am looking for the way that will (A) not switch the arrays order (B) IF POSSIBLE, not cause me to define any custom function.

Comment: There isn't an existing function doing exactly this but you may build one easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no existing function doing all this but you can add it :

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "prepend", {
  enumerable: false,
  configurable: false,
  writable: false,
  value: function(e) {
    this.unshift(e);
    return this;
 }
});
```

Then

```
[1,2].prepend(3)
```

will return `[3, 1, 2]`

Answer (score 2):

This should solve your problem:

`[3].concat([1,2])`

Comment: I can't switch the arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `unshift()`.

```
a = [1,2]
a.unshift(3)
```

But be carefull, don't use `[1,2].unshift(3)` as a value, if you need it functional do

```
(function (a) { a.unshift(3); return a; })([1,2])
```

Comment: unshift doesn't return the array but the element

Answer (score 0):

```
function cram(myArray):Array {
  myArray.unshift(3);
  // 3,1,2
  return myArray 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I Think unshift is the function

```
a = [1,2]
[1, 2]
a.unshift(3)
a
[3, 1, 2]
```

You will need to wrapp since return the length of the new Array. If you require return an array

Link to [doc](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unshift.asp)